# Css Carousel not sliding right amount

Tags: html, css

I followed a tutorial to make a css carousel but the images aren't moving the correct amount, I figure it's probably a problem with the @keyframes but am not sure what it needs to be changed to

[Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/utgkbbef/)

```
@keyframes carousel{
    0%    { left:0; }
    11%   { left:0; }
    12.5% { left:-100%; }
    23.5% { left:-100%; }
    25%   { left:-200%; }
    36%   { left:-200%; }
    37.5% { left:-300%; }
    48.5% { left:-300%; }
    50%   { left:-400%; }
    61%   { left:-400%; }
    62.5% { left:-300%; }
    73.5% { left:-300%; }
    75%   { left:-200%; }
    86%   { left:-200%; }
    87.5% { left:-100%; }
    98.5% { left:-100%; }
    100%  { left:0; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h9n1bu1/)

Comment: @Shniper If this is the right answer for your question you should mark it as accepted answer.